# XAP Packaging failed can't find resource path

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm stuck on a bit of a problem. I've uploaded an image for reference [here](http://i2.lulzimg.com/139c5ed7cf.jpg) and tried to get everything you need in to it.

Basically I've moved some images into a more structured way but Silverlight/Visual Studio is having none of it. I set the path to be relative but it is looking in C:/ for some reason.

I've Googled it but nothing solves my problem, they all just mention updating the references in WPAppManifest.xml - which you can see I have done.

If anyone can shed some light on the situation it would be much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Also using `"/Resources/Images/ApplicationIcon.png"` and `"(\)Resources\Images\ApplicationIcon.png"` do not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago, for exactly the same reasons: I wanted to restructure and cleanup the used resources, and got screwed over the same way, and with the same message.

The uri's, assuming they're relative, and "calculated" from the project folder should definitely look like

```
"Resources\Images\<etc>\<etc>"
```

I can't tell you for sure what the solution is, but here's how I "solved" mine:

- Make sure both the icon and background-image resources are set to
  Build Action "Content".
- Select both through the Application Page of the property page of
  the assembly.

To be honest, I have no idea why this worked (for me, at least), and I never got round to establishing the actual problem. In my case both my resources were already set as content, but manually entering the uri's in WMAppManifest simply did not work. I ***had*** to do it through the property pages.

Hope it works for you too. Should you stumble on a more definite answer, please share it :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. What do you mean by "Application Page of the property page"? Struggling to find where this is so I can do what you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Right click your project in the solution explorer, and select "Properties" from the context menu. This will bring up the properties for your project, with the "Application" page active. From there you can select the icon and background image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that got it to compile :-) Weird how changing the XML doesn't effect the properties.